# Multiple instances of AirFoil Speakers on one machine (Mac)

Tags: mac, airplay, airfoil

My Mac has two sets of speakers connected to its analog and digital outputs. I am currently using (with a great success) AirFoil Speakers to stream audio from iTunes/iOS to the analog ones (digital ones would work as well but only one at a time).

Is there a way to run two instances of AirFoil Speakers to make my mac appear as two different airplay devices, allowing me to choose to which speakers to output the sound?

I have tried force running another instance of AirFoil Speakers only one of them shows up in a list of available devices.

I guess I could install a Windows-based VM with sound support and run another instance there but that is a bit too much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this by using [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/) in conjunction with the airfoil speakers. Will report back if there are any co-existence issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple instances, but you have to tweak the settings inside the Airfoil app. Just clone it and open the package, you have to change the app name and the process name inside.